# What is the proper way to override inputAccessoryViewController so that it works on both iOS 9 and iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, ios10, inputaccessoryview

I am trying to implement a textView that floats about the keyboard (like the iMessage app) I want to use the `inputAccessoryViewController` so that I can have view controller, and not just a view by overriding `inputAccessoryView`.  I have written the code below but it has a problem in iOS 9 where the textView disappears when you tap and the textView on the keyboard pops up. It works fine in iOS 10.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var textEntryController = TextEntryController.fromNIB()

    override var inputAccessoryViewController: UIInputViewController? {
            return self.textEntryController
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true 
    }
}
```

I was trying to figure out what went wrong so I did override both `inputAccessoryViewController` and `inputAccessoryView` and put break points in each method.

```
    override var inputAccessoryViewController: UIInputViewController? {
        return self.textEntryController //break point
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return self.textEntryController.view //break point
    }
```

This fixes the problem of the textview disappearing on iOS 9, but I don't think that it is right.  This probably breaks the view controller hierarchy.

Observations:
On both iOS 9 and iOS 10 both methods get called when when I start the app
On iOS 9 ONLY the`inputAccessoryView` gets called when I tap on the textfield.
On iOS 10 BOTH the `inputAccessoryView` and `inputAccessoryViewController` get called when I tap on the textview.

What is the proper way to override `inputAccessoryViewController`? I don't think I should have to override both `inputAccessoryView` and `inputAccessoryViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue and in my case the `inputAccessoryViewController` and `canBecomeFirstResponder` override methods were not being called. It was because the `ViewController` was not a subclass of `UIViewController`.